# java public field when inherit

Tags: java

Assume there are two classes:

```
class A{
    public int a=0;
}
class B extents A{
    public int a=1;
}
```

I've tried this code:

```
A a=new B();
B a1=new B();
```

and `a.a` is 0, `a1.a` is 1.

Is there any method to access a1's super.a?

Comment: Define a method in B to return it

Comment: You could always do `((A) a1).a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in class B to fetch the value of superclass variable `a` through `super.a`

```
class A {  
    public int a=0;
}  

class B extends A {  
    public int a=1;

    public int superClassA() { 
        return super.a; 
    } 
}
```

Use `a1.superClassA()` to fetch the value for `a` from class `A`

Comment: It seems that we must use a function to get the value,isn't it right?

Comment: Yes because Java doesn't allow variable overriding.